# Issues instantiating class in composition project

Tags: php, oop, guzzle, composition

I have a task to access an external API and then render the results to a separate FE. I have made an ApiClass and a ProductListClass. Then from an index page I am including the two class files and then am trying to call the ProductListClass method, but I am getting an ApiClass not found error and can't quite work out why.

Here's my ApiClass

```
   <?php

namespace app\ApiClass;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class ApiClass
{
    protected $url;
    protected $client;

    public function __construct(Client $client)
    {
        $this->url = 'http://external-api';
        $this->client = new $client; //GuzzleHttp\Client
    }

    private function getResponse(string $uri = null)
    {
        $full_path = $this->url;
        $full_path .=$uri;
       $result = $this->client->get($full_path);
        return json_decode($result->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    }
    public function getData($uri)
    {
        return $this->getResponse($uri);
    }
}
```

This is my ProductListClass

```
<?php

include ("ApiClass.php");

class ProductList 
{ 
    private $apiClass;

    public function __construct(ApiClass $apiClass) {
        $this->apiClass = $apiClass;
    }

    public function getList() {
        $urlAppend = 'list';
        $list =  $this->api->getData($urlAppend);
        if(array_key_exists("error", $list)) {
            $this->getList();
        } else {
            return $list;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the index page

```
<?php

include_once 'app/ProductListClass.php';
include_once 'app/ApiClass.php';

$api = new ApiClass();

$productList = new ProductList($api);
$productList->getList();
```

and this is the error I am getting

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ApiClass' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/index.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/index.php on line 6

Comment: Using @shudder answer I managed to get this working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate ApiClass from correct namespace, and fully qualified name (FQN) for your `ApiClass` is `app\ApiClass\ApiClass`. You need to either call

```
$api = app\ApiClass\ApiClass();
```

or use only class name by importing the namespace in the file header:

```
use app\ApiClass\ApiClass;

include_once 'app/ProductListClass.php';
include_once 'app/ApiClass.php';

$api = new ApiClass();
...
```

Namespaces are declared for each file, so that you could not change them by including files in different contexts. No namespace defined in the file means that it's global namespace (like your `ProductListClass`).

#### GuzzleHttp\Client

If you're passing `Client` instance to your ApiClass you need to have it already instantiated and there's no need to use `new` on it again. If you take FQN string as a parameter you may do that, but that's not a good practice (unless you're doing this kind of magic in some dependency injection library).

So either do this (preferred):

```
class ApiClass
{
    ...
    public function __construct(Client $client)
    {
        $this->url = 'http://external-api';
        $this->client = $client;
    }
```

with api instantiation:

```
$api = new ApiClient(new GuzzleHttp\Client());
```

Or instantiate inside constructor without parameters:

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->url = 'http://external-api';
        $this->client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    }
```

Ps. I think you should learn to use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) and its autoloading (automatic include class files) - working with libraries (and your own classes) will be much easier.

Comment: @BarryWatts I've expanded my answer - you should do the same with question I guess.